# Problems with Postgrestql and Django in Manjaro linux, after update

Tags: django, linux, database, postgresql, manjaro

I'm making a blog app in Django, and I'm using Postgres as database, since I read it is the best database for django.

I am developing in Manjaro linux, a rolling release distribution, and I recently updated my system,
after the update I got an error with the database.

```sh
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file. You must specify the --config-
file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

So after search for a solution I decided to reinstall Postgres, and after reinstall it, more problems happened.

Now that I want to start Postgres i get the following error:

```sh
 postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-01-14 13:19:00 -05; 6s ago
    Process: 55976 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch postgres[55976]: "/var/lib/postgres/data" is missing or empty. Use a command like
ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch postgres[55976]:   su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch postgres[55976]: with relevant options, to initialize the database cluster.
ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 14 13:19:00 daniel-arch systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

I tried to do the following command as the error says,

```
su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
```

But I don't know why the password I used to use in order to access to the database is incorrect. Now I don't know how can I access to the postgres user, or how to reinstall postgres completely, so I have a totally new database.

Also referring to the Django part, I can't run the server, there is a way that I can have my database independent of my local system, since if I upgrade my system again probably postgres will break up also.

Can I use something like Docker, to have the applications I'm developing independent of my local system?

Comment: find and check the `pg_hba.conf` file ... I have never used manjaro, so have no idea how it sets-up postgres by default.  But in **most** cases a *failed* password has to do with the connection options in the aforementioned file.

Comment: Looks like there is not that file in my system: `find: ‘pg_hba.conf’: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Try `find / -name pg_hba.conf` ...

Comment: I think that it isn't in my system, but It there is a file like that in timeshift, a recovery software, Do you recommend me to recover the files before the update?

Comment: Hard to say - as I said; I'm not familiar w/ manjaro.  It would be worth trying, doesn't look like you could make it any worse by trying; that, and you can always delete it again.

Comment: [This](https://dev.to/tusharsadhwani/how-to-setup-postgresql-on-manjaro-linux-arch-412l) suggests that there **should** be a pg_hba.conf created during install - not sure what went wrong in your case.